# Twitter4J doesn't seem to properly authenticate

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to use Twitter4J and for some reason I am not able to properly authenticate.I am getting an error that something is wrong with my authentication. I have tried all the different methods available online but none of them seemed to be working. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? accessToken, accessSecret,etc. all seems to be correct.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessSecret);
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a); 
    //twitter.verifyCredentials();
    System.out.println(twitter.getScreenName());
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get consumer secret/token and access token/secret from [https://dev.twitter.com/](http://Twitter%20Developers)

Try this code.

```
       String consumerKey = "yourconsumerKey ";
       String consumerSecret = "yourconsumerSecret";
       String accessToken = "yourAccessToken";
       String accessSecret = "yourAccessSecret";

       ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
       cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
           .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
           .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
           .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
           .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);

       try 
       {
          TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
          Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
          System.out.println(twitter.getScreenName());
       }catch (TwitterException te) {
          te.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(-1);
       }
```

Comment: I have already done that. Your code is the same. I tried it with now success.